IP denials and Apache
I am using Apache 2.2, and my .htaccess file is filled with "deny from"s to restrict IP access. You know, recognized spammers and the like. In upgrading to Apache 2.4, I am told that IP denials should be in the form "require not". Um, does that mean I will have to reqwrite my whole .htaccess file? Apache 2.4 doesn't understand "deny from"? That would be a pisser.

You're reading that wrong, I think. There's nothing in the Apache 2.4 docs that says anything about deny from [host] being deprecated; it's still documented as being fully functional. Require [not] is used for user authentication, and while it does include the option Require not ip [range] the original deny from is still supported.
That said, you might consider moving those deny from directives out of .htaccess and into your site config file. The config file is read once when Apache restarts; .htaccess is read, recursively through your directory tree, with every page load.

Sensible stuff - there's just so many things wrong with mantaining a blocklist in a .htaccess file. OTOH and if it were required, automating the editing of a repeating pattern in a file with a well-defined syntax SHOULD be trivial.

Thank you. That clears up a lot. Now, my domain is Hostgator, and I don't think I have access to my config file. Or maybe I do? I don't know where to look for it.

If you're on Hostgator, almost certainly you're using cPanel. I know that there is a way to do it in cPanel, but I am by no means an expert; cPanel has its own way of doing things that subverts a lot of what site admins usually do. I think we have a StackExchange area for cPanel, Plesk, Webmin, and other site management tools, but its name escapes me at present.

I use cPanel regularly, and have inspected it carefully for Apache options. Haven't seen any "config" there. But maybe you can point me to it?

Every vendor seems to configure cPanel slightly differently, so I can't be certain what you have. But one of my cPanel sites has an "IP Blocker" option under Security that should do what you need. Less than optimal, perhaps, but better than .htaccess.

Yep, I do have "IP Blocker". Now, why is that better than .htaccess?

Deny/Allow/Order are 2.2 directives, available only for compatibility with old configurations through mod_access_compat module, many people get confused and mix them with Require directives getting odd results, so what people should do now, in 2024, after 8 years since the deprecation of 2.2, is to stop loading mod_access_compat and stop using those directives.

@user637 it's better than .htaccess because it is not loaded multiple times with each page load.

@DanielFerradal Perhaps, but the Apache 2.4 docs are nowhere near that emphatic.

@tsc_chazz  In my whole reply I posted two links which clearly say those are solely for compatibility purposes and you should migrate. The message is clear, neon signs and caps are not needed imo.

For directories or elements where you want to Deny access directly, like root filesystem and such, substitude any Allow/Deny/Order directive with
Require all denied

The sane thing would be to reject access from / and allow where you need it, like in documentroot path.
For paths like in documentroot where you want to give access just:
Require all granted

Example in server config context:
<Directory />
   Options Followsymlinks
   Require all denied
   AllowOverride none
</Directory>

And in the working virtualhost:
<Directory /path/to/documentroot>
  Require all granted
</Directory>


About Order/Allow/Deny/Satisfy.
Consider 2.2 was deprecated in 2017, that is almost 8 years ago. It is about time to move from old Order/Allow/Deny directives, unload mod_access_compat, and use the more simple and easy to understand 2.4 directives in that regard.
About certain comment I read regarding Apache HTTP documentation not saying those directives are deprecated just check Compatibility section in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html where it clearly says:
Compatibility:    Available in Apache HTTP Server 2.3 as a compatibility module with previous versions of Apache httpd 2.x. The directives provided by this module have been deprecated by the new authz refactoring. Please see mod_authz_host
There is also Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2 advicing against using and mixing the old directives with new ones and anyone should consider upgrading and abandoning old directives when ready.
Also some behaviours are different in 2.2 than 2.4 so the sooner you migrate to new directives the better.
